# PPTP server not functioning (or set up) correctly

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, lan, pptp

I've set up a PPTP server on Ubuntu Sever 14.04. I need to allow a foreign client to access the LAN, but NOT attempt to use my internet connection. When connecting to the VPN the client loses internet connectivity presumably because my PPTP server is not set up to allow use of my internet to clients (which is how I want it). All I want this to do is enable the client to "join" my LAN and access SMB shares on the local network etc. I have tried disabling "default gateway" on the client's connection to the VPN.

How do I get this to work as intended?

My router is set up to point PPTP to the server. I am going to include the configuration files used to set up PPTP so that people more knowledgable than myself can hopefully pick up on where I've gone wrong.

The only thing I've done in /etc/pptpd.conf:

```
# (Recommended)
localip 192.168.0.1
remoteip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
# or
#localip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
#remoteip 192.168.1.234-238,192.168.1.245
```

/etc/ppp/chap-secrets:

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
vpnuser1        pptpd   password1               "*"
```

[A screenshot of the client's network setup](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxm9LVxEKx1gVTBHcklHU05NaVE/edit)

Comment: What's probably happening is that you are setting the VPN clients to use the same IP subnet as many home routers... i.e. their LAN or Wifi connection will receive 192.168.0.10 and you are setting the VPN to give an IP in the same range so the traffic is being sent over the VPN and then being blocked. Try chagning the VPN IP range to `remoteip 192.168.1.234-238,192.168.1.245` and a `localip 192.168.1.1` - i.e. invert the comments above! Even then, SOME routers use the 192.168.1.x range.... if this is still a problem then you may want to look at 192.168.2.x range..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer: You need to change the range of IPs that your VPN server is assigning to your remote clients.**

The range of IPs you have selected conflict with consumer grade (home/soho) routers - they normally assign DHCP clients the same range of IPs that your VPN server is assigning (192.168.0.x). As a result, your clients are sending requests destined for your router (the gateway)(and thus the "Internet") down the VPN and (because your server is blocking that "final destination" (a regular Internet request)) they are having their Internet requests blocked.

Be careful, however, the configuration you have posted has an "alternative" set of IPs (192.168.1.x) that the VPN server can use. Although these will work, there are a number of consumer grade routers that also use this range of IPs for LAN clients.

I would, therefore, recommend that you change your VPN IP range (in `/etc/pptpd.conf`) to:

```
localip 192.168.2.1
remoteip 192.168.2.234-238,192.168.2.245
```

If you are happy with 192.168.1.x range then, of course, you can use this, but remember my warning above.